# Implementation Direction For Fetching a table and validating

Tags: c#, sql, .net, rules

Kindly excuse my silly request for some ideas, suggestions and a quick snippet of code, I am new.

I have a requirement like 4 columns of a table that contains business rules. These needs to be fetched from SQL and `

> `each row contains the columnns -  rule name, threshold 1, threshold 2, threshold3.`

I want to fetch these table values only once and store in memory and loop through for each rule and validate for threshold1, threshold 2 and threshold 3.

If it meets threshold condition, in the logic I want to set a status.

I am really struggling to come up with code/syntax to implement this below:

1. How would I fetch these and put in a list of object? An example for the above please?
2. How would I loop through and check for threshold and validate?
3. If it meets threshold 1, exit loop and set the rule name and status in output.
4. If it meets threshold 3, continue for next row check but put the rule name in output and say status too.

You can say any status for this example...can someone please assist me with some sample code and sample naming convention object????

`

Comment: The best way is to use SQL DataAdatper and put results into a datatable.  I assume the rows should also include a status column from the database.  The you  can change the status value in the datatable and use the datatable accept change property which will put status back into the database.

Comment: @jdweng: Thank you but it looks very 3-4 decades old style (Using ADO objects) lol...but I can still use, but definitely adapter and data tables are pretty old mate...Something using list (Object) and loop through is what I am looking for. You can write a small snippet of code for requirement above? I am really clueless as am a busienss analyst in developer role for bread lol

Comment: You do not need a list object the datatable is the list.  The SQL Server store/retrieve data  in random order.  So you need to use an OrderBy (like by date) to be able to test each row like you are asking.  To get data I normally use : foreach(DataRow row in dt.AsEnumberable()) { //your code here }.  You can get each column : row.Field<int>("Column A")

Comment: @jdweng: ta, well yes but data table and all 2 decades old style...I feel super old to use such things today...I wanna use list :p :) Trendy and fashionable.. lol please help me?

Comment: Why create an anonymous list when you have the Data Adapter that does all the work automatically?  DataTables are not old fashion.  Anonymous lists are not as efficient as declared objects.

Comment: @jdweng: ok how to do thank you...

Comment: That is what the foreach was showing in previous posting.

Comment: @jdwengok :)...